# install dlib on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, dlib

I've installed dlib according to the instructions on the [official site](http://dlib.net/compile.html). I've also complied the examples and done the unit test, everything is fine.

However my Cmake couldn't find it by `find_package(dlib REQUIRED)` in another project, and gave the following error message

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "dlib" with any of
  the following names:

    dlibConfig.cmake
    dlib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "dlib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "dlib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "dlib"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Please help, thanks!

If I remember correctly there's no such problem on ubuntu 14.04, `message(STATUS ${dlib_DIR} ${dlib_LIB})` should give something like `/usr/local/lib/cmake/dlib`, `/usr/local/lib/libdlib.so`.

Comment: `However my Cmake couldn't find it by find_package(dlib REQUIRED)` - Precise error message, please. `The include and lib directories are like ...` - the first path is definitely wrong (include dir shouldn't contain neither `lib` nor `cmake` parts); please, fix it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, I've fixed that

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I have to add `include(xxx/dlib/dlib/cmake)` to make cmake aware of the library.

I've totally forgot that I manually placed the files in those directories `/usr/local/lib/cmake/dlib, /usr/local/lib/libdlib.so` for the convenience of including them on that Ubuntu 14.04 system.